# CollapsingToolbar doesn't fully collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `Navigation Drawer Activity` (NavActivity) in which one of the fragments (OuterFrag.xml) has a `Collapsing Toolbar` and a `View Pager`. When I scroll in the `View Pager`(InnerFrag.xml), the toolbar collapses, but not fully. Here's the image and the code before I go any further..

[image: The part in red should be completely gone!]

[OuterFrag.xml](http://pastebin.com/MDgNQz6F)

[InnerFrag.xml](http://pastebin.com/AigWxpeF)

The problem has to be in OuterFrag, which contains the `CollapsingToolbar`. I've tried setting the height of the `CollapsingToolbar` to "1dp", but then a black Toolbar appears with the same size of the red are in the image above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

I removed the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `CoordinatorLayout` and the `AppBarLayout` and now, the Toolbar collapses completely!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside a fragment which is inside a fullscreen activity, removing all the `fitSystemWindows="true"` will make it work.